# screen zoomed into top left when qemu vm with gpu is open

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, xrandr, zooming

When running a vm with a gpu added as virtual hardware (quadro 4000) in qemu, the screen zooms into the top left corner. This persists even after closing the vm. Rebooting the computer does not fix this issue. The only fix I have found so far is a full restart. I tried running

```
xrandr --output default  --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0       --rotate normal \
           --fb 1920x1080   --panning 1920x1080
```

but it returns

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
X Error of failed request:  BadRRCrtc (invalid Crtc parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  29 (RRSetPanning)
  Crtc id in failed request: 0x521
  Serial number of failed request:  21
  Current serial number in output stream:  21
```

(I put the output as "default" because that is what

```
xrandr | grep " connected"
```

returned)
I also tried uncommenting #GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480 in /etc/default/grub and changing 640x480 to 1920x1080. (my monitor size) (there is also only one monitor)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm restart
```

also doesn't fix this issue.
As I am new to linux, I may have missed some relevant info but am willing to provide (almost) anything.